# PHP Generate x amount of random odd numbers within a range

Tags: php, random, numbers

I need to generate x amount of random odd numbers, within a given range.
I know this can be achieved with simple looping, but I'm unsure which approach would be the best, and is there a better mathematical way of solving this.

EDIT: Also I cannot have the same number more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Generate x integer values over half the range, and for each value double it and add 1.

ANSWERING REVISED QUESTION: 1) Generate a list of candidates in range, shuffle them, and then take the first x.  Or 2) generate values as per my original recommendation, and reject and retry if the generated value is in the list of already generated values.

The first will work better if x is a substantial fraction of the range, the latter if x is small relative to the range.

ADDENDUM: Should have thought of this approach earlier, it's based on conditional probability.  I don't know php (I came at this from the "random" tag), so I'll express it as pseudo-code:

```
generate(x, upper_limit)
  loop with index i from upper_limit downto 1 by 2
    p_value = x / floor((i + 1) / 2)
    if rand <= p_value
      include i in selected set
      decrement x
      return/exit if x <= 0
    end if
  end loop
end generate
```

`x` is the desired number of values to generate, `upper_limit` is the largest odd number in the range, and `rand` generates a uniformly distributed random number between zero and one.  Basically, it steps through the candidate set of odd numbers and accepts or rejects each one based how many values you still need and how many candidates still remain.

I've tested this and it really works.  It requires less intermediate storage than shuffling and fewer iterations than the original acceptance/rejection.

Comment: That can result in a number over the range. E.g. if my range is 50, I'll get 25, 25*2+1 = 51

Comment: @carazh I assumed that the range would be specified in terms of an allowable odd number.  Regardless, my answer doesn't apply now that the question has been revised.

Comment: Yes, thanks also! Similar approach in another answer also. Much obliged, both of you!

Comment: The final sentence is an important one. If x is close to the range, this can deteriorate badly.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Yeah, I'd definitely recommend using a hash for the already generated set in case 2, so at least the check for duplicates can be done in constant time per attempt.

Comment: @pjs Without measuring, I strongly suspect that shuffle will be faster for all but the most extreme cases of very small x.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe There shouldn't be many duplicates/rejections if x is below around sqrt(range).  For example, to generate x = 1000 values in the range 1 to 999,999 I'd prefer acceptance rejection to storing and shuffling a million numbers.

Comment: @pjs This would certainly fall into the category of very small x. Though I'm hesitant without measurements to quantify the x N relation. Note: Shuffling should not require extra storage.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe How do you shuffle without maintaining an array or set with all the candidates?  Looks to me like that's O(range) storage, vs O(x) storage for acceptance/rejection methods.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @pjs Knuth, The art of programming Vol 2 seminumerical algorithms,  pps 33-36.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe pps 33-36 doesn't seem to apply, Knuth gets into shuffling in the sense of permutations of a set around p140, and uses an array notation for exchanging set elements.  Similarly, in your solution you generated the whole set and then invoked shuffle on it.  It sure looks to me like you're generating and storing all the candidates and then slicing off an appropriate subset.  Contrast with acceptance rejection, which generates individual candidates and includes/excludes them one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a list of elements in the range, remove the element you want in your random series. Repeat x times.

Or you can generate an array with the odd numbers in the range, then do a shuffle

Generation is easy:

```
$range_array = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < $max_value; $i++){
    $range_array[] .= $i*2 + 1;
}
```

Shuffle

```
shuffle( $range_array );
```

splice out the x first elements.

```
$result = array_slice( $range_array, 0, $x );
```

This is a complete solution.

Comment: Edited, since answer has been edited also. That's something to start with, thanks!

Comment: To find unique random values, this is as sophisticated as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mt_rands($min_rand, $max_rand, $num_rand){
    if(!is_integer($min_rand) or !is_integer($max_rand)){
        return false;
    }
    if($min_rand >= $max_rand){
        return false;
    }
    if(!is_integer($num_rand) or ($num_rand < 1)){
        return false;
    }
    if($num_rand <= ($max_rand - $min_rand)){
        return false;
    }
    $rands = array();
    while(count($rands) < $num_rand){
        $loops = 0;
        do{
            ++$loops; // loop limiter, use it if you want to
            $rand = mt_rand($min_rand, $max_rand);
        }while(in_array($rand, $rands, true));
        $rands[] = $rand;
    }
    return $rands;
}

// let's see how it went
var_export($rands = mt_rands(0, 50, 5));
```

Code is not tested. Just wrote it. Can be improved a bit but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

This code generates 5 odd unique numbers in the interval [1, 20]. Change $min, $max and $n = 5 according to your needs.

```
<?php
function odd_filter($x)
{
    if (($x % 2) == 1)
    {
        return true;

    }

    return false;
}

// seed with microseconds
function make_seed()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
    return (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000);
}
srand(make_seed());

$min = 1;
$max = 20;
//number of random numbers
$n = 5;

if (($max - $min + 1)/2 < $n)
{
    print "iterval [$min, $max] is too short to generate $n odd numbers!\n";
    exit(1);
}

$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)
{
    $x = rand($min, $max);

    //not exists in the hash and is odd
    if(!isset($result{$x}) && odd_filter($x))
    {
        $result[$x] = 1;
    }
    else//new iteration needed
    {
        --$i;
    }
}

$result = array_keys($result);
var_dump($result);
```